# D.O.H. test for document.domain

Tags: javascript, html, testing, dojo, doh

I am trying to write a D.O.H. test for a function which determines if the current environment is running in either production or a local development machine.  The function accomplishes this by analyzing the string in the document.domain property.  Is there a way to programmatically set the document.domain property so that when the function is called from the D.O.H. test, the domain I specify will get analyzed?  Here is the function:

```
isProdEnvironment = function() {
        var nonProdRegExp = new RegExp( 'localhost|dev|test|perf' );
        var isNonProd = nonProdRegExp.test( document.domain );
        return ! isNonProd;
    };
```

In my test case, I wanted to do something like:

```
document.domain = 'someProdEnvironment.com';
doh.assertFalse (isProdEnvironment());
```

However, everytime I do this, the test always passes due to the fact the document.domain call in the `isProdEnvironment()` function keeps retrieving the domain of the development machine that my tests are running on (i.e. 'localhost').

Comment: Why are you not using `window.location.hostname`?

Comment: my understanding was that `window.location.hostname` and `document.domain` are equivalent

Comment: *"eeps retrieving the domain of the development machine that my tests are running on (i.e. 'localhost')."* Wait, you are running this page on localhost and wondering why it is always returning true?

Comment: I am always running it on localhost during development, but I need make sure the function works on different domains (i.e. not localhost).  That is why I wanted to know if I could programmatically set window.location.hostname or document.domain.

Comment: I believe it would be a security issue if that was writeable. Why don't you just use a regular variable in your test instead of document.domain?